# RSA encrypt/decrypt between C and python

Tags: python, c, openssl, rsa

I have server written in `python` and client in `C` . Their job is to send a secret message from server to client which is encrypted with `RSA private key`. I am using `openssl/rsa.h` library, that is I initialize a `rsa` object with a private key and encrypte a message with `RSA_public_encrypt(length_of_message, "Secret Message", to, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)` . Then I send this encrypted message to `python` server and try to **decrypt it with same private key** using `from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA` library. Problem is that it does not decrypt it properly. It always outputs 128-bit length message where the secret message is randomly placed in it `(e.g. '\x23\xa3x\43...Secret Message\xef\x4a')`, where it should normally return just `Secret Message`.

Comment: "decrypt it with **same private key using**" - that better be a typo.

Comment: For encrypting in RSA scheme you should use public key...

Comment: I am using `RSA_public_encrypt(length_of_message, "Secret Message", to, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_PADDING)` which encrypts public. When I generate public key from private and use it, functions gives errors.

Comment: I think it is related with standard padding options, but I can not solve it yet. When I encrypt with `rsautl -encrypt -in msg.file  -inkey tvfp.pem  -out  out.bin` and decrypt with `openssl rsautl -decrypt -in out.bin  -inkey tvfp.pem` it works properly. However, when I add `-raw` option for padding while decrypting, it prints out similar result to python decrypter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was about the padding. Python's rsa module decrypts result with `PKCS1` padding and does not removes padding. With the function below which I have taken from [here](https://kfalck.net/2011/03/07/decoding-pkcs1-padding-in-python) problem was solved:

```
def pkcs1_unpad(text):
if len(text) > 0 and text[0] == '\x02':
    # Find end of padding marked by nul
    pos = text.find('\x00')
    if pos > 0:
        return text[pos+1:]
return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to create a same pair of RSA key in Python and C . please find the code below and let me know if any modification needed to get it worked.

Code in python

```
   key = RSA.generate(2048)
   file_out_pub = open("pubkey.der", "wb")
   file_out_pub.write(key.publickey().exportKey())
   file_out_pub.close()
   file_out_pub = open("pubkey.der", "`enter code here`r")
   public_key = RSA.importKey(file_out_pub.read())
   cipher = PKCS1_OAEP.new(public_key)
   password = pw
   ciphertext = cipher.encrypt(password)
```

Code in C

```
 int clen = 0, num, ret;
 clen = strnlen_s(req->pw,2048);
 unsigned char ptext[2048];
 RSA *rsa = RSA_new();
 BIGNUM *e = BN_new();
 ret = RSA_generate_key_ex(rsa, 2048, e, NULL );
 num = RSA_private_decrypt(clen, req->pw , ptext, rsa, RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING);
 // Start authentication process
 strncpy(req->pw,ptext,MAX_PASSWORD_STR);
```