# How to decrypt an RSA encrypted file in Python

Tags: python, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I am having some trouble with RSA decryption in Python.

I have generated a pair of RSA private and public keys using OpenSSL command. A string "**abcde**" is stored in **message.txt** file. Then I encrypt the file with this command:

```
openssl rsautl -in message.txt -encrypt -pubin -inkey public_key.pem > encrypted.txt
```

There is no problem if I use the `openssl rsautl` command to decrypt the  **message.txt** file. However, when I try to decrypt the message in Python, the result is strange.

**Python code:**

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

f = open("encrypted.txt","r")
encrypted = f.read()
f.close()

f = open("private_key.pem","r")
private_key_string = f.read()
private_key = RSA.importKey(private_key_string)
f.close()

decrypted = private_key.decrypt(encrypted)
print decrypted
```

**Result:**

[image]

String "**abcde**" can be decrypted and shown. But a lot of strange characters are also produced in front of it. What's wrong with the Python code? Should I use Python-Crypto?

Comment: Looks like padding, as RSA encrypts a fixed number of bytes, with the data at the end. Beyond that, I don't know why the API includes it or how you would remove it.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I have fixed this issue with the padding removal code here: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22398745/rsa-encrypt-decrypt-between-c-and-python